# JavaScript To Display Selected Items On Screen

Tags: javascript, php, select, get

I am attempting to `echo` the selected results from this multi-select onscreen.  However my syntax is not `echo` the data on screen.

What should change so that it properly displays the selected values?

```
<select name="dothis" size="15" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>

foreach ($_GET['dothis'] as $selectedOption)
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

Comment: In your code there is no <?php, just forgot in sample or error in original code?

Comment: @GeorgiyDubrov - just omitted from sample above.

Comment: What is url of page where you are rendering list? Meaning get params

Comment: It is on the same page as the `select` syntax - directly below it

Comment: What is the example of value in `$_GET['dothis']`?

Comment: I understand this, in your code you have $_GET, so can you provide url to understand what are you trying to echo?

Comment: @u_mulder - an example value would be whatever is selected.  I.E. let's take a hypothetical and say one was selected, I would want one echo on screen.

Comment: @GeorgiyDubrov - using the variable $_GET must it redirect to a new page or is it capable of capturing on the same page?  I am not redirecting to a new page, I am simply wanting to as the item is selected write to secreen.

Comment: It wouldn't work. Php is on serever side, and without page reloading (by submitting form, for example) it knows nothing about what did you selected. You need js for this

Comment: Very interesting.  Thank you for that insight!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would echo a selected option:

```
                    <select name="dothis" size="15" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
    <option <?php if (isset($_GET['dothis']) == "one") { echo "selected "; } ?>value="one">one</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_GET['dothis']) == "two") {
            echo "selected ";
        } elseif (!isset($_GET['dothis'])) {
            echo "selected ";
        }?>value="two">two</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_GET['dothis']) == "three") { echo "selected "; } ?>value="three">three</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_GET['dothis']) == "four") {
            echo "selected ";
        } elseif (!isset($_GET['dothis'])) {
            echo "selected ";
        }?>value="four">four</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($_GET['dothis'] as $selectedOption)
        echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

Comment: This is not echo the selected statements on the page?

Comment: That's because no options will be selected until the form is submitted, but now I see what you're trying to do. Try this: This will show options two and four as being selected by default.